# Understanding the meaning of "scalar multiplication" in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading Gallian's "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" (4th ed.) and have just reached the first chapter on rings. All of the material in the chapter deals with, as expected, the behavior of rings, including how addition and multiplication interact.

In the exercises are the following:

> 14. Show that if $m$ and $n$ are integers and $a$ and $b$ are elements from a ring, then $\left(ma\right) \left(nb\right) =\left(mn\right) \left(ab\right) $.

> 15. Show that if $n$ is an integer and $a$ is an element from a ring, then $\left(-na\right) = - \left(na\right) $.

> 16. Let $a$ and $b$ belong to a ring $R$ and let $m$ be an integer. Prove that $m\left(ab\right) = \left(ma\right) b=a\left(mb\right) $.

I can't find anywhere in the chapter an explanation for the definition of multiplication of an arbitrary ring's element by an integer, but I'm assuming it just means repeated addition, i.e., $$ na = \underbrace{a + a + \cdots + a}_{n \text{ times} }. $$ With this definition, the exercises' claims are intuitive and the proofs are fairly straightforward.

My question is: am I interpreting this correctly? Is this standard notation, as shorthand for repeated addition in rings? It seems like it's easy to confuse with the multiplication operation in the ring, especially when the ring is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$. If our ring is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$, I've convinced myself that this notation for repeated addition *is* the same as multiplication by an integer, since that's literally how we define multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$. But for another type of ring, for example, the ring $M_2\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)$ of all $2\times 2$ matrices with elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ under the typical matrix addition and multiplication, this shorthand is more confusing: $2A$ looks like the scalar multiple of matrix $A$, but that's different from $A+A$.

Edit: I just realized that was a bad example because of course $2A = A+A$ in that ring of matrices. But my question still stands more generally.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation of the symbolism is correct. And, generally, _every_ Abelian group, including additive groups of rings, thus becomes a $\mathbb Z$-module. (A "module" is like a vector space, except that the "field of scalars" is not necessarily a _field_ and it may be _a ring_ (with unity).)

Comment: Of course. Your definition only works for positive integer (or non-negative integers, if we assume an empty sum is $0,$ which we often do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation of what "scalar multiplication by an integer" means is correct.

At the risk of complicating the matter, I will make the following remark: suppose we denote scalar multiplication by a dot, and ring multiplication by juxtaposition; if $n\in \mathbb Z$ and $s\in R$ is given by $s=\underbrace{1_R+\dots+1_R}_{\text{$n$ times}}$, then the two notions of "multiplication" coincide, i.e. $n\cdot a=sa$ for every $a\in R$. You can prove this using the distributive property of rings.

This means, that, for example, in the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices, the notation $2A$ can be read in two equivalent ways: if you think of $2$ as denoting the integer $1+1$, and the multiplication as being scalar multiplication, then you get the same answer than as you would if you think of $2$ as denoting $1_R+1_R$, and the multiplication as being ring multiplication. This is essentially what Frank's answer is saying.

Comment: That assumes $1_R$ exists, though, and this actually works in non-unital rings - indeed, in any commutative additive group.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I’m not sure I understand. What exactly are you referring to when you say “this actually works”?

Comment: Scalar multiplication by integers works in any (abelian) additive group, not just in rings.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Sure, I just mean that in a (unital) ring, the two notions of multiplication are actually very closely connected. In a non-unital ring or abelian group written additively, an expression like $2r$ only admits one possible interpretation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct.

Here is another way to interpret what $na$ means. First, solve this exercise: show that there is a *unique* ring homomorphism $\iota$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to any ring $R$.

The homomorphism $\iota$ allows us to canonically identify any integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with the element $\iota(n) \in R$. Thus, we can interpret $na$ as the product $\iota(n)a$, which is just the usual multiplication operation of $R$. If you have solved the above exercise, it should be easy to show that this agrees with the interpretation of $na$ as repeated addition.

If $\iota$ is injective, it identifies $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subring of $R$, which you alluded to in your post. In fact, the uniqueness of $\iota$ implies that the image of $\iota$ is the *unique* subring of $R$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. However, note that $\iota$ is not necessarily injective. To get some intuition for $\iota$, I'd recommend computing it for a few examples (e.g., $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$, $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$).

Comment: Quibble: maybe unique ring hom such that $1$ is mapped to the unit in $R$ (which we assume _has_ a unit), etc, ... I know, sometimes it is supposed to be implicit that "ring homs" are of rings with units, and that the unit is mapped to the unit... but at an introductory level it might be good to be explicit about such things.